# Set column value based on email address regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

My Rails application is targeted at college students -- only Berkeley and University of Washington students can sign up right now, and I use a regex to do it. The user model has a column in it called "school" that I'd like to fill with the name of their school based on their email address. Here's an example of what the validation might look like in my User.rb file (with just Berkeley):

```
berkeley_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@berkeley\.edu\z/i
  validates :email, :presence => true, :format => {:with => berkeley_regex}
```

In the User controller, how could I go about setting the @user.school column to be Berkeley, for example, or University of Washington if I add a regex to recognize that email domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the regex matching into a method.

You could associate the regex with a key in a hash, too, making this easier, roughly:

EMAILS = {
"Berkeley": /\A[\w+-.]+@berkeley.edu\z/i,
"Washington": /whatever/
}

Iterate over the hash to get the value and regex:

```
EMAILS.each do |school, regex|
  # If it matches, return the `school` value
end
```

Use the *same* method for your email validation by validating `:email` against the method instead of a simple regex as detailed in the [Custom Validation section of the Active Record Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations). You may need to tweak the return value etc. to get the function to work for both things, or write a thin wrapper for the validation around the lookup.

Consider a callback to actually set the value, e.g., `:after_validation` or `:before_save`.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new method that returns Berkeley or U of Washington depending on which regex matches.

Next, you will want to do an update on the user so:

```
user_school = find_what_school_user_goes_to(@user.email)
@user.update(:school user_school)
```